# i am facing a problem in my react native app

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-native-reanimated

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'E:\Hunain documents\AdamProject\AdamNew\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 450
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating script.

> Calling `[node, E:\Hunain documents\AdamProject\AdamNew\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]` finished with an exception. Error message: groovy.json.JsonException: Unable to determine the
> current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object

The current character read is 'i' with an int value of 105
Unable to determine the current character, it is not a string, number, array, or object
line number 1
index number 0
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
^. Output: info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

how can i resolve this .please help me